# How would I setup a model for use with SSR in another game engine?

Tags: export

I'm attempting to use Panda3D with an extension for PBR. However, upon exporting my model, the default Blender enviroment map is put in somewhere, this causes it to reflect off of the grassy plains that Blender shows by default. I am attempting to change this.

**My main question here is: How do I export without using a baked in enviroment map?**

The research I've done indicates that somewhere Blender is baking in the enviroment map as (rather then an issue with my code):

1. Models with some sort of SSR option on (I have no clue what it is) work as normal.
2. My models (I tried with a simple metalic cube) don't work, reflecting off of the afformentioned world.

Googling the issue turned up nothing. Can anyone help? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was working, just not in the way one would think.

So, basically, what was happening was that it was not only reflecting off of the default world, but also onto the in game world. I didn't look close enough to notice, but that's what was happening.

In order to "fix" this, you need to set the enviroment map to an empty white (or black, or any other color for that matter) so that your true reflection will be overlayed on top.